# Renew windows surface tablet developer license

Tags: windows, windows-8

Hi guys I have a surface tablet which has an application a friend of mine made installed on the device. However when I try and run the app it says the app cannot open please go to the windows store. Upon doing that I am greeted with a developer license has expired and that i need to renew the license. But how do i do this? I have researched several websites and they are mentioning using visual studios but I do not have this on my surface tablet and have never used it.So how can I renew the developers license on my surface tablet so i can continue to use the app my friend has designed for me?

Answer (score 0):

Use your Outlook/Hotmail/Live username and password.
And give a try.

Comment: it has not asked me for any login details sir so where is it you suggest i use my username and password

Comment: have you signed in with your Outlook/Hotmail id on the tablet?

Comment: yes i have using the account that i have verified with microsoft so yes i am logged in

Comment: [Try this](http://mmman.itgroove.net/2013/03/fix-for-error-your-developers-license-has-expired-to-continue-to-use-this-app-please-renew-your-license-after-performing-a-system-restore/)

Answer (score 0):

Question is about the developer license of the person who developed the app.
Your friend has to launch visual studio and sign in with the account he used while developing your app. This automatically renews his dev licence for 30 days.

And if this isn't enough, you need to re-install the app.